# can i make the "animate" wait amount of time and then run?

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

idk if its possible but 
lets say i have a **animate** or **whileInView**
and i have delay on the animation like that

```
varinats={
  initial:{opacity:0},
  whileInView:{
    opacity:1,
    transition:{delay:1}
  },
}
```

i want to make it wait 2s and then run the animation and the animation delay work also

i tried to add the global transition prop but didnt work

```
varinats={
  initial:{opacity:0},
  whileInView:{
    opacity:1,
    transition:{delay:1}
  },

 //---global transition---
 transition:{delay:2}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in `variants`: `varinats`.

Comment: can u elaborate more please or put a link for more details